# onChange on TextInput Not Working Inside Formik

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, native-base, yup

Generally `<TextInput>` allows you to type even when you're just specifying a placeholder. However, when using within the Formik form, I am unable to type and validate anything in my form. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried `onChangeText`with `setFieldValue`and `handleChange`both.

```
const initialValues: FormValues = {
  friendEmail: '',
};

export const Page: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showPage,
}) => {

  const validationSchema = emailValidationSchema;

  const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    (data: any) => {
      //console.log('Email', initialValues.friendEmail);
      if (data) {
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
         ...
        } else {
          addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id));
        }
      }
    },
    [addFriend],
    //[friendEmail, addFriend],
  );

  const [loadUsers] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: getFriendId,
    onError: _onLoadUserError,
  });

  const handleSubmitForm = React.useCallback(
    (values: FormValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>) => {
      console.log('Submitted');
      loadUsers({
        variables: {
          where: { email: values.friendEmail },
        },
      });
      //setFriendEmail('');
      values.friendEmail = '';
    },
    [loadUsers],
    //[loadUsers, friendEmail]
  );

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={showPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View>
          <View>
            <View>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({
                  handleChange,
                  setFieldValue,
                  setFieldTouched,
                  handleBlur,
                  handleSubmit,
                  isSubmitting,
                  values,
                }) => {
                  const setEmail = (friendEmail: string) => {
                    setFieldValue('friendEmail', friendEmail)
                    setFieldTouched('friendEmail', true, false);
                  }
                return(
                  <Form>
                  <View>
                    <View>                  
                      <Item>
                      <TextInput
                      placeholder="Email"
                      onChangeText={setEmail}
                      //onChangeText={handleChange}
                      //onChangeText={handleChange('friendEmail')}
                      //onChangeText={e => console.log('Workinggg')}
                      //onBlur={handleBlur('friendEmail')}
                      //value={values.friendEmail}
                      autoCapitalize="none"
                      />                      
                      </Item>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Button
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text>
                          Add{' '}
                        </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  </Form>
                )}}
              </Formik>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

How can I fix the textInput to make the typing and validation work?

According to this: 
https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/react-native

We don't need to use the name property. I have used this onChangeText too but I still can't write anything.

Comment: Instead of passing `onChangeText={setEmail}` prop to `TextInput` pass 
`onChange={handleChange}`

Comment: Already tried that. I still can't type anything into it @TridevMishra

Comment: Then maybe I am not correctly wrapping it all within Formik?

Answer (score 2):

In your case if your `TextInput` returns value at first parameter like you use all right. But you mistake give `name` to field:

```
<TextInput
  name="friendEmail"
  placeholder="Email"
  onChangeText={setEmail}
  autoCapitalize="none"
/>
```

`Formik` doesn't know where to set your value if you don't give name to field.
And also you can do like:

```
<TextInput
  name="friendEmail"
  placeholder="Email"
  onChangeText={(val) => {
    setFieldValue('friendEmail', val)
    setFieldTouched('friendEmail', true, false);
  }
  autoCapitalize="none"
/>
```

My advice is to modify or write wrapper for `TextInput`. And field should return `onChange` first parameter `name`, and second `value`. It will be more useful.
And you can read more about your problem on official [docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field#name).

Comment: The property name doesn't exist on TextInput or Input. It always gives ```No overload matches this call.```

Comment: @a125 Strange. But `formik` understands fields with `name`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Formik Hooks. Here is a code you can use and adapt to yours:

```
import {useFormik} from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
});

const TestFormik = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    },
    onSubmit: async (values, {setSubmitting}) => {
      console.log(values);
      setSubmitting(false);
    },
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={formik.handleChange('email')}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur('email')}
        value={formik.values.email}
        placeholder="Email"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={formik.handleChange('password')}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur('password')}
        value={formik.values.password}
        placeholder="Password"
      />
      <Button title="Submit" onPress={formik.handleSubmit} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by simply adding the touched object and handle blur method to the formik and validate your textinput on the these conditions will solve your issue here is the code snippet

```
<Formik
        initialValues={{
          email: '',
          password: '',
        }}
        validationSchema={formSchema}
        validateOnChange={true}
        validateOnBlur
        onSubmit={values =>
          handleCreate(values.email, values.password)
        }>
        {({
          values,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          touched,
          errors,
        }) => (
          <>
            <TextField
              label={'Email'}
              onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
              value={values.email}
              // onFocus={()=>setEmailFocused(true)}
              onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
            />
            {errors.email&&touched.email && (
              <View flexDir={'row'} alignItems={'center'} mt={1} ml={2}>
                <View
                  bg={'red.500'}
                  h={1}
                  w={1}
                  rounded={'full'}
                  mx={1}></View>
                <Text color={'red.500'} fontSize={12}>
                  {errors.email}
                </Text>
              </View>
            )}
            <TextField
              label={'Password'}
              onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
              value={values.password}
              onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
            />
            {errors.password &&touched.password&& (
              <View flexDir={'row'} alignItems={'center'} mt={1} ml={1}>
                <View
                  bg={'red.500'}
                  h={1}
                  w={1}
                  rounded={'full'}
                  mx={1}></View>
                <Text color={'red.500'} fontSize={12}>
                  {errors.password}
                </Text>
              </View>
            )}
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate('ForgetPassword');
              }}>
              <Text
                fontSize={'16'}
                mr={2}
                textAlign={'right'}
                color={'pro'}
                mt={4}
                fontFamily={'Jost-Medium'}>
                Forgot Password?
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View mt={'40%'}>
              <AButtons label={'Sign In'} loading={isLoading} onPress={()=>{if(values?.email!==''||values?.password!==''){handleSubmit()}
            else{
              setEmailFocused(true);
              setPasswordFocused(true);
            }
            }} />
            </View>
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
```